# Why demo Jquery plugin isn't working?

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, field, autofill

I downloaded the autocomplete plugin, just a complete plugin demo. The only thing that i need to do is upload the SQL file to my database and update the database login details:

```
/* Database setup information */
$dbhost = 'localhost:3307';  // Database Host
$dbuser = 'root';       // Database Username
$dbpass = '';           // Database Password
$dbname = 'itemsdb';      // Database Name
```

When i take a look in the console then i getting some XML errors, every time i type something in the search field.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xkz1w.jpg
This is the autocomplete plugin: https://www.freshdesignweb.com/downloads/jquery-autocomplete-p1.zip

Comment: what you have tried yet show us some code and one more thing can you list some errors you are getting in console.... @PcWolf

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to run this from your own folder, but not using a local webserver. The issue is explained in here - ["Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." error when loading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)

Comment: Thank you. I uploaded the folder to my localhost server. Now everything is working fine!